# How do I specify module paths for Jest tests?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

It does not appear to respect the `NODE_PATHS` env variable, and instead just looks in the current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment Jest doesn't support `NODE_PATH` in its module resolution code (for no reason other than the fact that it just wasn't ever built).

We're tracking the issue here for now: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/102

Answer (score 9):

Ran into the same issue where Jest didn't respect webpack module resolve alias.

In `jest.config.js`:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    'Services(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/services/$1'
}
```

You can now use the following import statement:

```
import { validateEmail } from 'Services/utilities';
```

Answer (score 8):

From Jest doc:

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration

in `package.json` define:

```
"jest": {
  "modulePaths": [
    "<rootDir>/src/"
  ],
},
```

Answer (score 7):

Jest does not read NODE_PATH. In our project where we use webpack we faced problems with `alias` and `moduleDirectories`. Jest didn't resolve paths correctly. So we solved that like this:
Suppose you want to import

```
import SomeComp from 'components/SomeComp';
```

which is located in `/src/components/SomeComp/index.js`

In `package.json` define:

```
"jest": {
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "/src/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
  }
},
```

Comment: not working for me, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633346/set-absolute-path-for-jest-in-react-project

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, here's how I fixed it.
Let's say you are trying to import src/components/404.vue
in your package.json:

```js
... 
  "jest": {
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>/src/components"
    ]
  }
...
```

the absolute path '/src/components/' can now be resolved in your 404.test.js as:

```js
import Page404 from '404.vue'
```

Answer (score 0):

just put this inside your package.json

```
"jest": {
  "modulePaths": [
    "<rootDir>"
  ],
},
```